# How to get current Area, Width and Height (with respect to latitude and longitude) of current map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say I have a map inside a `div` with width `x` and height `y` with t zoom level. How can I find the area, width and height of the currently visible map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
var spherical = google.maps.geometry.spherical, 
    bounds = map.getBounds(), 
    cor1 = bounds.getNorthEast(), 
    cor2 = bounds.getSouthWest(), 
    cor3 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor2.lat(), cor1.lng()), 
    cor4 = new google.maps.LatLng(cor1.lat(), cor2.lng()), 
    width = spherical.computeDistanceBetween(cor1,cor3), 
    height = spherical.computeDistanceBetween( cor1, cor4);
```

Comment: I was going to say that there is no need for a geometry library when calculating the distance between points on a line... then I remembered we live on a sphere. #fezgame

Comment: Great answer - note that you must specify explicitly that you want to use the geometry library when initialising the map/api.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58, 60),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }

      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          place.icon,
          new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
      marker.setIcon(image);
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
                    place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                   (place.address_components[1] &&
                    place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                   (place.address_components[2] &&
                    place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                  ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

and ur define ur HTML components similar to...

`<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>`

add following line line to header..
`<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
      type="text/javascript"></script>`

**EDIT**
You can get height and width from google.maps object.. I couldn't alter the code for your requirement. But I am sure this will give you a good idea.

**Good Luck**

Comment: from where did you copy paste this.

Comment: Where is width, height, area of available map?