# How to get the height of a Google Maps map inside a larger div, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a map inside a `div` with `id=mymap`. I am able to get the heigh of the `div` via `document.getElementById('mymap').clientHeight` or `$('#mymap').height();`

I am wondering how to get the height of the Google Maps map inside this taller `div`. As you can see by the exposed grey (gray) above and below the blue ocean in the image, the map is slightly shorter than the div.

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you need any other info. Also, note that this question is different than the question [How to get current Area, Width and Height (with respect to latitude and longitude) of current map?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9528675/664833)

Comment: If you are asking about the grey areas, they are actually part of the map tiles (above approximately +/- 85 degrees of latitude).  Your map is filling up the "mymap" div.  You can calculate the pixel position of those latitudes using API methods.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I was able to find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240226/664833